# Metadata Design tab in Sites 9.5 and 9.6

Tags: cme, sites-9.5, metadata, sites-9.6, experience-space

In 9.5 and 9.6 it is now possible to use the Metadata Design tab of a page schema, instead of using an embedded metadata schema, for both XS and CME.  A nice technical and business-oriented discussion about this in
[What is the best practice for implementing Page metadata?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/21381/what-is-the-best-practice-for-implementing-page-metadata)

A few questions regarding the Metadata Design tab:

- As all components will be stored in a region of a page, admins can equally choose to store metadata at the region schema Metadata Design tab instead of the page schema Metadata Design tab if there is a single region?
- As with pages, metadata can be stored in the Metadata Design tab instead of an embedded metadata schema for a component?  And this would be the preferred mode of storing metadata moving forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, (page) Region metadata is preferred over Page-specific metadata. Though XS allows for both as of Tridion Sites 9.6.

At the Component level, you could place Metadata fields directly in the Schema's Metadata fields or in an embedded Schema. There are no changes with Component metadata, though using an embedded Schema is useful to reuse the same set of fields across multiple Schemas.